# Variables on Magento checkout success page

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to setup ROI on my Magento website on success page.

For this I need a variable from the order which is :

- **PRODUCT_ID** - This should be an array containing all products in the order

So far I've tried the following code :

```
<?php
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($this->getOrderId());
    $items = $order->getAllItems();
    $itemcount=count($items);
    $name=array();
    $ids=array();
 ?>

<?php foreach ($items as $itemId => $item) { 
   $ids[]=$item->getProductId();
} /* PRODUCT_ID - not showing anything */?>
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Dom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$this->getOrderId() is giving you the increment_id, not the entity_id for the order. You can load the order this way:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
```

The actual entity_id for the order is stored in the session:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId()
```